# How to tell which facebook version API i'm using in php

Tags: php, facebook

I have an old php project from about two years ago.  I see that I downloaded the facebook php SDK version 3.1.1.

When I installed my project, I see the PHP facebook object make a call to `/me/friends?access_token=longadfjoaisdfjoaije` which then prints all my friends.

I've read lots of discussion that facebook graph v2.0 and onwards will no longer disclose all the friends unless the friends are also using the app/project I made and explicitely agree to some instructions.

So i'm trying to confirm if my FB SDK is connecting to a graph api less than 2.0.  But I can't tell.  My guess is that i'm using less than 2.0 because i'm seeing all my friends in the api response.   I tried digging through the SDK code but I don't see anywhere the disclosure of which graph api version I'm using.  Does anyone know how I determine which graph version I'm using via the 3.1.1 version of Facebook SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct, Facebook PHP SDK v3.1.1 <strike>uses Graph API v < 2.0</strike> uses < v2.0 if was created before API v2 was introduced, otherwise the API v2 is used (as stated at [How to tell which facebook version API i'm using in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330810/how-to-tell-which-facebook-version-api-im-using-in-php/26330841?noredirect=1#comment41333262_26330841))

You can get it from the code:

The old SDK does not add a version number https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L1185

Whereas the new one adds it explicitly https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php#L216

```
  protected function getRequestURL()
  {
    return static::BASE_GRAPH_URL . '/' . $this->version . $this->path;
  }
```

where `$this->version` is assigned to `const GRAPH_API_VERSION = 'v2.0';`

Comment: Ok thanks zerkms.  I guess it's safe to assume that sometime in the near future, my 3.1.1 sdk will stop returning the full list of friends at `/me/friends` if any at all.  Or am I mis understanding something? thanks

Comment: @John yes, I believe so. Cannot find when exactly it happens though. I would even say that it's all api v1 that will stop working, not just `/user/friends` endpoint https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions + https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: "Facebook PHP SDK v3.1.1 uses Graph API v < 2.0" - that´s not correct, it just does not add a version number as you stated. so if you create a new app NOW, it will use v2.1.

Comment: @luschn: so the `v2.0` part is not required for API to serve API v2? Did not know that, thanks

Comment: not in a newer app, no. if you create a new app, it will be the latest api version by default and you can´t use an older one.